# PyQt. TypeError

Tags: pyqt

I set filter on my QMainWindow with this:

```
keyPressFilter = keypressfilter.KeyPressFilter(self)
self.installEventFilter(keyPressFilter)
```

KeyPressFilter itself:

```
class KeyPressFilter(QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(KeyPressFilter, self).__init__(parent)


    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            print "key press %d" % event.key()
            return True
        else:
            return QObject.eventFilter(obj, event)  <- line NN
```

and i getting endless errors with every eventtype QEvent\QPaintEvent\QHoverEvent\etc:

```
line NN, in eventFilter:
TypeError: QObject.eventFilter(QObject, QEvent): argument 2 has unexpected type 'QPaintEvent'
```

How can i get rid of it?

Thx in advance,

Serge

Comment: example in documentation :   https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtCore/QObject.html?highlight=installeventfilter#PySide6.QtCore.PySide6.QtCore.QObject.installEventFilter is still reporting wrong text --> return QObject.eventFilter(obj, event)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`eventFilter()` is not a class method, so you need to pass `self` as well:

```
return QObject.eventFilter(self, obj, event)
```

Comment: example in documentation :   https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtCore/QObject.html?highlight=installeventfilter#PySide6.QtCore.PySide6.QtCore.QObject.installEventFilter is still reporting wrong text --> return QObject.eventFilter(obj, event)